# Como capturar un valor de date picker en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Amigos, buen día:

Podrían ayudarme con un atoron que tengo? De antemano gracias.

Estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario pero estoy teniendo problemas al poder pasar un valor de un datepicker a código de PHP. Simplemente es que cuando le de click a un botón, este haga una consulta a MYSQL tomando en cuenta el valor del date picker. Subo una imagen con el ejemplo de mi codigo.

### Lista de llamadas entrantes - Equipohotel

---

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['aksi']) == 'delete'){
            // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
            $nik = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_GET["nik"],ENT_QUOTES)));
            $cek = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM log_llamadas WHERE codigo='$nik'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($cek) == 0){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> No se encontraron datos.</div>';
            }else{
                $delete = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM log_llamadas WHERE codigo='$nik'");
                if($delete){
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> Datos eliminado correctamente.</div>';
                }else{
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> Error, no se pudo eliminar los datos.</div>';
                }
            }
        }
        ?>


        <form class="form-inline" method="get">
             <!--<p>Fecha &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;inicial: <input name="fechainicial" class="form-control" type="Date" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"></p>
             <p>Fecha &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;final: <input name="fechafinal" class="form-control" type="Date" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"></p>-->
             <p>Fecha &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;inicial: <input name="fechainicial" id = "fechainicial" class="form-control" type="Date" id="datepicker"></p>
             <div class="form-group">
                Filtro de estado: <select name="filter" class="form-control">
                    <?php $filtroestado = (isset($_GET['filter']) ? strtolower($_GET['filter']) : NULL);  ?>
                    <option value="4" <?php if($filtroestado == 'Todos los registros'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Todos los registros</option>
                    <option value="1" <?php if($filtroestado == 'Contestada'){ } ?>>Contestada</option>
                    <option value="2" <?php if($filtroestado == 'No contestada'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>No contestada</option>
                    <option value="3" <?php if($filtroestado == 'Aplazada'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Aplazada</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        <input type="submit" name="filtrar" value="Filtrar" onchange="form.submit()">
        </form>


        <br />
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th><th>Fecha&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>    <th>Hora</th>
                <th>Empleado</th>   <th>Motivo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
                <th>Teléfono</th>   <th>Contacto/Cargo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   <th>Estado</th>   <th>Nota/Razon</th>   <th>Editar</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if($filtroestado == 1){
                       $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM log_llamadas WHERE estado= 1  ORDER BY codigo ASC");
                       }
                       else if($filtroestado == 2){
                       $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM log_llamadas WHERE estado= 2  ORDER BY codigo ASC");
                       }
                       else if($filtroestado == 3){
                       $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM log_llamadas WHERE estado= 3  ORDER BY codigo ASC");
                       }
                       else if($filtroestado == 4){
                       $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM log_llamadas  ORDER BY codigo ASC");
                       }
                        else{
                            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM log_llamadas  ORDER BY codigo ASC");
                       }


            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
                echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No se encontraron datos con los criterios de busqueda.</td></tr>';
            }else{
                $no = 1;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
                    echo '
                    <tr>

                        <td>'.$row['codigo'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['fecha'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['hora'].'</td>

                        <td><a href="profile.php?nik='.$row['codigo'].'"> '.$row['empleado'].'</a></td>
                        <td>'.$row['motivo'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['telefono'].'</td>
                        <td>'.$row['cargo'].'</td>
                        <td>';
                        if($row['estado'] == '1'){
                            echo '<span class="label label-success">Contestada</span>';
                        }
                        else if ($row['estado'] == '2' ){
                            echo '<span class="label label-danger">No contestada</span>';
                        }
                        else if ($row['estado'] == '3' ){
                            echo '<span class="label label-warning">Aplazada</span>';
                        }
                    echo '
                        </td>
                        <td>'.$row['nota'].'</td>
                        <td>

                            <a href="edit.php?nik='.$row['codigo'].'" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                            <a href="index.php?aksi=delete&nik='.$row['codigo'].'" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm(\'Esta seguro de borrar los datos '.$row['empleado'].'?\')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                    $no++;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><center>
```

[image: Datepicker]

Comment: el código va como texto y no como imagen, por favor edita y corrige

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Adicional colocar codigo en formato imagen esta muy mal visto, edita tu pregunta y coloca tu codigo en formato texto

Answer (score 1):

creo que la funcionalidad que estás buscando es Ajax, te recomiendo buscar en internet acerca de ella, esta tecnología te permite interactuar en forma real entre tu front (HTML) y tu backend (PHP) que también debería estar en un archivo aparte que se encargue de recibir las llamadas y devolver información, separando así las capas de tu aplicación. Para hacer esto, hay que hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
$("#datepicker").change(function(){
  var value = $("#datepicker").val();
  $.ajax({
    url:"miurl.php",
    data: value
  }, function(response){
    console.log(response);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="datepicker">
```

Ten en cuenta que en el momento en el que tu página termina de cargar por primera vez tu código PHP es estático para ese momento, por lo cuál tienes que usar asincronismo con Ajax para tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Buscare lo que me mencionas, excelente dia.